# Should a woman pray when she has discharge?

Tags: salat, women, taharah, menses

I had my period a week ago and am back on the contraception pill, but experienced some discharge on my liner when I have gone to the bathroom a few times today and want to know if I can just clean myself and continue prayers for the day?  Or should I wait until tomorrow to see if it's cleared up and if so carry out the daily prayers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You cannot pray until even minor spotting is stoppped. and you cannot just Clean that blood and pray. if even there is small spot, you need to take Ghusl (obligatory bath) and then pray

Answer (score 2):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

> Narrated Fatimah daughter of AbuHubaysh: Urwah ibn az-Zubayr reported
>   from Fatimah daughter of AbuHubaysh that her blood kept flowing, so
>   the Prophet (ﷺ) said to her: When the blood of the menses comes, it is
>   black blood which can be recognised; so when that comes, refrain from
>   prayer; but when a different type of blood comes, perform ablution and
>   pray, for it is (due only to) a vein. Abu Dawud said: Ibn al-Muthanna
>   narrates this tradition from his book on the authority of Ibn 'Adi in
>   a similar way. Later on he transmitted it to us from his memory:
>   Muhammad b. 'Amr reported to us from al-Zuhri from 'Urwah on the
>   authority of 'Aishah who said: Fatimah used to have her blood flowing.
>   He then reported the tradition conveying the same meaning. Abu Dawud
>   said: Anas b. Sirin reported from Ibn 'Abbas about the woman who has a
>   prolonged flow of blood. He said: If she sees thick blood, she should
>   not pray; if she finds herself purified even for a moment, she should
>   was an pray. Makhul said: Menses are not hidden from women. Their
>   blood is black and thick. When it (blackness and thickness) goes away
>   and there appears yellowness and liquidness, that is the flow of blood
>   (from vein). She should wash and pray. Abu Dawud said: This tradition
>   has been transmitted by Sa'id b. al-Musayyab through a different chain
>   of narrators, saying: The woman who has a prolonged flow of blood
>   should abandon prayer when the menstruation begins; when it is
>   finished, she should wash and pray. Sumayy and others have also
>   reported it from Sa'id b. al-Musayyab. This version adds: She should
>   refrain (from prayer) during her menstrual period. Hammad b. Salamah
>   has reported it similarly from Yahya b. Sa'id on the authority of
>   Sa'id b. al-Musayyab. Abu Dawud said: Yunus has reported from
>   Al-Hasan: When the bleeding of a menstruating woman extends (beyond
>   the normal period), she should refrain (from prayer), after her menses
>   are over, for one or two days. Now she becomes the woman who has a
>   prolonged flow of blood. Al-Taimi reported from Qatadah: If her
>   menstrual period is prolonged by five days, she should pray. Al-Taimi
>   said: I kept on reducing (the number of days) until I reached two
>   days. He said: If the period extends by two days, they will be counted
>   from the menstrual period. When Ibn Sirin was questioned about it, he
>   said: Women have better knowledge of that.([Sunan Abi Dawud](http://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/1/286))

In Regard to your query the condition you mentioned is not menstrual period,fuqaha have mentioned that there must be 15 days difference in two menstrual cycles and minimum days for bleeding considered for periods would be 3 days and maximum would be 10 days but it depends on your monthly routine cycle ,assuming your condition it is the vein blood called as Istihadha which is considered as disease and in this disease one has to perform prayers,fasting etc,after menses one has to perform Ghusl and if someone suffers from istihadha now she just need to perform wudhu for every prayer ,Ghusl is not obligatory for every prayer so you could just clean it ,do wudhu and you have to perform your prayers.

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Faqirah's [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/30571/17163), here's a hadith from Sahih al-Bukhari, Book of Menstrual Periods:

> Narrated `Aisha: Fatima bint Abi Hubaish said to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! I do not become clean (from bleeding). Shall I give up my prayers?" Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) replied: "No, because it is from a blood vessel and not the menses. So **when the real menses begins give up your prayers and when it (the period) has finished wash the blood off your body (take a bath) and offer your prayers**." -- Sahih al-Bukhari 306 ([sunnah.com](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/6/11))

There's a distinction between menses and other forms of discharge.  As you say, she should clean the private parts from impurity, and redo wudu before prayer.  E.g.:

> These brown discharges or spots which you have before the menses are not menses. ...  Nonetheless, she is obliged to clean her private parts from the yellowish and muddy-colored discharges as these invalidate ablution.  -- [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=94252); see also [another IslamWeb fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=91095)
>
> This brownish discharge that came after doing ghusl does not matter and is not regarded as menstruation ... -- [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/50059)
>
> The default is that anything that exits from either private parts nullifies ritual ablutions (wudu), for both men and women. Such things are also considered in themselves ritually impure (najis). [Haskafi, Durr al-Mukhtar, Bab al-Ghusl] -- [SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/01/26/does-vaginal-discharge-break-wudu/)

Answer (score -1):

So if you have discharge before you get your period for the first time it’s ok to pray but if it’s after the period you can still pray but only if it’s discharge but not spotting or  period blood